# Connect to database with database-specific user with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

I have used CMS' before (Joomla, Wordpress, Drupal) - the way I typically do it is to create the database, then I go into the database and create a user that has all privileges for that database specifically (non-global).  Then I can install the CMS using that user and password I created.  So I know that user can connect and do things!

Now I'm trying something non-CMS and my connection looks like this (this is on my local box using XAMPP):

```
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "myDatabase-Specific-User";
  $pass = "myUserPassword";
  $databaseName = "myDatabaseName";
  $tableName = "pre_tableIwant";
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) ;
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
```

But I get errors connecting with that and it won't let me connect.

If I use a GLOBAL user with that same code (i.e. root, or another user I create that has access to ALL the databases) I can connect and get my information fine.  But I want to keep things limited (for security) and only use a user that has rights to that specific database.

Any ideas?  I realize this is probably a newbish question - but I'm kind of stumped as to why it won't work

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'myDatabase-Specific-User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: check the myDatabase-Specific-User privileges

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: And mysql_connect is deprecated don't use it in new code.Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Comment: @Heberfa - he has all the privileges locally for that database.

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 - yes, phpmyadmin

Comment: Hi, after some research, you could try to reinstall XAMPP, if it would not be a hassle

Comment: @InfiniDaZa - this is a fresh install of XAMPP.

Comment: Yes, but reinstalling could help.

Comment: I'm thinking I may just create another 'global' user with rights similar to root and use that for now - because I can't find a solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PDO_MySQL and got it all working appropriately utilizing PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the web host, you may need to change 'localhost' to the actual database host. I know that if you use hosting24 or 000webhost, this is the case. Sometimes it can be msql.xxx.com for example.

Comment: Sorry - I'm using XAMPP - this is on my localhost - I will update the question!  Thanks!

Comment: oh I see I'll try to find out what's wrong. This ones got me :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mysql user has access to both `%` (wildcard) and `localhost` connections, they are different. Usually if the database is on the same machine as webserver, then you need `localhost`

Comment: it should be localhost - and the user does have access to that.